# I am looking for a way to use BasicAuth like a l5-very-basic-auth in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am looking for a way to use AuthenticateWithBasicAuth with the independent user id and pass in Laravel 7.
I tried AuthenticateWithBasicAuth using like this.

```
Route::get('/show', 'Controller@show')->name('debugShow')->middleware('auth.basic');
```

this auth.basic seems to use user_id and passwords that are users table that Laravel auth created.

Comment: [l5-very-basic-auth](https://github.com/olssonm/l5-very-basic-auth) works in L7 why don't you just use that?

Comment: is that so? I thought l5 means it works only L5.

Comment: That's just the name of the package. The author probably didn't expect to work on it very long so thought it was safe to call it "Laravel 5 something" there's a version compatibility table in the github page for the actual versions it supports

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't seem to work in v7.11.0.
```
$ composer require olssonm/l5-very-basic-auth:5.*
  - Installing olssonm/l5-very-basic-auth (v5.6): Downloading (100%)         
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
In VeryBasicAuthServiceProvider.php line 74:
         
  Call to undefined function Olssonm\VeryBasicAuth\str_random()  
              
Script @php artisan package:discover ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
Installation failed,
```

Comment: `olssonm/l5-very-basic-auth (v5.6)` why does it choose to download v5.6 ? Can you change that to v6 ? that's the required version for L7

Comment: Thank you. It went well.